# Naming Convention for using source in StreamBridge SPRING CLOUD STREAM

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

im using streamBridge in 2 different locations like this:

```
streamBridge.send("first", "hello1");
```

```
streamBridge.send("second", "hello2");
```

now the problem is that the docs say that i can use the source directly while naming destinations like this

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.first.destination=topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.second.destination=topic
```

now what i dont understand it how this property work: i added 2 sources as what i named as i want them to be ready at initialization

```
spring.cloud.stream.source=first,second
```

now as per docs to set the destination i need to add this as sources added works like fucntions and their naming is the same

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.first-out-0.destination=topic
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.second-out-0.destination=topic
```

will i need to put in out-0 or just use the name I put in source name property?

also if i need to use only 1 binding source in 2 different streamBridge uses, can I do so? or i need to use 2 different and then map them to same destination as per i need?

Answer (score 1):

StreamBridge will send to whatever name you put as a first argument.
This means that if a binding does not exist it will be created provisioned and used.
If it does exist it will be used.
However there are cases where such dynamic bindings need to be pre-configured ahead of time. In that case you are using `spring.cloud.stream.input-bindings` or `.output-bindings` properties - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/bindings.html#explicit-binding-creation. (`spring.cloud.stream.source` is deprecated and will be removed soon).
In those cases you treat the binding name as a function and depending if it's an input or output binding you add a `0-in` or `0-out` prefix.